# Slider Effects in wordpress site

Tags: wordpress, user-interface, jquery-ui, slider

I am working on a WP website. I want add this kind of effects in my slider, www.netrootstech.com. Can anyone tell me about this type of effects? Is there any particular name of these effects ? How to google it ?  Currently I have simple images on my slider and I am using Slider revolution. 
Regards

Comment: use revolution slider wordpress plugin

Comment: I am already using this plugin .

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The animated effect is an HTML5 canvas animation. You can try and Google that. Codepen is a good place to find those types of animations.

Comment: Thanx @jose. Is there any wo plugin through I can implement this in my slider